# Making create DB user and create DB instance, run over existing values with the same name

Tags: mysql

I tried to **recreate** a DB user and a DB instance (run over the existing ones), so I ran the following two commands in the Mysql CLI:

```
create user '${test}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
create database ${test};
```

I got this output:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'test'@'localhost'

The reason for the error, ofcourse, is because the user already exist).

### My question

How could I make sure the above commands will run over the existing data if I already have a DB user and a DB instance with the same value (`test`)?

### Update after answer

`mysql -V` brings:

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `if not exists` in your queries. For example:

`create if not exists user '${test}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';`
or 
`create database if not exists ${test};`

Your mysql version might be different, refer to right version. But more information could be found at:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html

Comment: `if not exists`? But these does exist, I want to run over / run through, the existing ones with the same name (or otherwise I've missed the point).

Comment: I've edited the question to best explain myself.

Comment: @Arcticooling And what should in your opinion be the result of "running over" an existing user? You can run `drop user` first.

Comment: It would be better to understand what you want to achieve with "running over"? Change passwords for existing users?

Comment: By running I mean to reacreate them arbitraraily --- you could say it's one action combining drop and create for the same value, I guess.

Comment: So to recreate you would need to drop existing user first. Otherwise you can use create command with condition to create user only when it doesn't exist (example above). Dropping and recreating is not best option, as you could loose all data in database (in case of creating database), or existing user's password - they will be forced to change it again.